# Powering a Patch Panel

Tags: ethernet, wiring, cat5e, rj45

So I'm in the process of replacing all the telephone wall plates with ethernet plates so I will have the choice to hardwire to the internet from any room if I so desire. right now I have my internet modem in my kitchen from there I have ethernet cord going from my modem to the wall plate that I changed(Let me add at the start of all this I rewired the wall plates to be compatible and work as I have CAT5 wired through my house). NOw the wire running from the kitchen to my garage, where the control panel is located is being used as the master feed to essentially provide internet to the rest of the house. Now the rest of the rooms that have a wall plate have CAT5 wiring going to them as well and all these wires are connected to a patch panel. the patch panel is great if it serves the purpose needed which is feed the rest of the house with the data provided by the main kitchen feed wire.

So my question is how do I Punch the main kitchen wire into the panel so it can provide the data and to all the rooms also punched onto the panel? I've tried googling but only getting info on how to much to panel, nothing on how to power or bring a feed to the panel that will power all the wires connected to that panel. Is it even possible with this type of panel? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWTXS.gif)

Comment: Home IT questions are off-topic here, but I think this question is probably ok for https://superuser.com

Comment: Is it actually CAT5, or is it possibly Cat6? There's a difference.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M  it is CAT5 E

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide power to a patch panel.

I'm guessing that you've plugged the CAT5 cables from all of the rooms into the front ports on the patch panel. What you need to do is to punch them down to the rear of the patch panel and then plug a cable from the front ports of the patch panel into a network switch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to upload a photo, I don't know if it's showing up, if not click where it says "enter image description here". That's all I have for a patch panel and I don't know if it is designed only for telephone usage what. When I started all this that is exactly how the panel was wired minus the line for the kitchen, it was wired on the left side as well with the rest of the lines. on the right side, there were both the blue wires connected to the line coming in from outside. I'm assuming this was the telephone line to connect the phone line to the house.

Comment: OK. That's not a patch panel. It's a punch down block. It can't be used for what you want to use it for. A punch down block is for creating a "one-to-one" physical connection between a single "set" of wires on one side to a single "set" of wires on the other side. It can't be used to create "one to many" physical connections.

Comment: Ok that makes complete sense then. so if i wanted to hard wire to one specific room could i do it with this punch down? If so would i just need to connect to the 2nd row of punch down clipsof the desired room im wanting to connect?

Comment: Honestly, and in my opinion, the best thing to do would be to put in a network patch panel (like in the images in my answer) and put in a a network switch. Trying to use the punch down block is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I agree I was asking just for personal knowledge. Until I'm able to get one ordered and delivered I could hook up my modem from there, cap off the CAT5 wires and plug them in to feed those outlets essentially right?